# Querying subcollection's field and get parent DocumentSnapshot in firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My requirement if a other user has saved my number on their mobile,i want to get his profile data.Now I am querying the mobile field,which is inside the contacts sub collection.when I make query I get document snapshot of the subcollection's document.But,I want to get Whole profile data of that user so,I need to get the parent snapshot.How can i achieve this or else do i have to change the structure of firestore? Thanks in advance

[[image: This is how my firestore structure looks1]

```
db.collectionGroup("contacts")
        .whereEqualTo("mobile",preference.getMobile()?.number)..get().addOnSuccessListener { snapShots ->
        val list = ArrayList<UserProfile>()
        for (s in snapShots) {
               //here i'm getting the contact data
           val contact = s.toObject(ModelMobile::class.java)
              //My need is getting userProfile Data
            /* val contact = s.toObject(UserProfile::class.java)
             list.add(contact)")*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the query on the contacts subcollection you will need to make another query for the parent document.  It's not possible to get them both at the same time in a single query.

```
for (s in snapShots) {
    var parentDocRef = s.reference.parent.parent
    // Now you have to get() the parentDocRef to get its contents
}
```

Comment: Oh k...I didn't know that..Thanks a lot!